# FaunaDB Graph query returns error Must provide schema definition with query

Tags: graphql, elm, faunadb

I am  trying to query **FaundaDb** **GraphQL** from my Elm js code. I am using `dillonkearns/elm-graphql` graph libray in my Elm code

I get the following error message:

```
{ 
  "data":null,
  "errors":[{
      "message":"Must provide schema definition with query type or a type named 
       Query."}]
}
```

The Jason request body of the Post to the fauna **api** endpoint is:

```
{"query":
query 
   {  
    userByUserName37286792: userByUserName(userName: "user123") 
    {   name    
        games {      
            data {        
                 ...
                }
            }  
        }
    }
```

If I paste this graph query into the Fauna graph playground it works. When I look at browser debugger to see what is actually sent using this query, the initial "query" word is removed. {  userByUserName37286792 ...

Last point.  I uploaded my scheme file to Fauna with some custom type and a Query section

```
type Query {
  allUsers: [User]
  userByUserName(userName: String!): User
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turn out I did not have correct connection settings in my Elm GraphQL query.

Before I had:
    Graphql.Http.withHeader "Authorization" ("Bearer [token '']

Below is my new Elm Graph query that works.

```
Query.userByUserName { userName = userName } userSelectio
|> Graphql.Http.queryRequest "https://graphql.fauna.com/graphql"
|> Graphql.Http.withHeader "Authorization" " Basic [token] "
|> Graphql.Http.send (RemoteData.fromResult >> GotUserInfoResponse)
```

I still not sure why I got this error?  I would think I would get a connection error.